# How to take specific text in each textbox line and print it

Tags: c#

I have one textbox(textBox1), inside of that textbox there are a lot of lines that are containing, let's say people's names and lastnames, divided by ':', example:

Liam:Williams

Noah:Davis

Lucas:Garcia

Ethan:Lee

There is left side and the right side divided by ':'.
My question is: How can I take out what's on the left(or right, doesn't matter) and print it in textBox1?

Comment: Please show the code you are trying to use, `.Split` would work, but you probably need to split it twice, difficult to tell without seeing what you have

Comment: You need to make this question clearer. For instance, how many textboxes are there. show the exact text you have, and the out put you desire